# how to know when a work in a thread is complete?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I need to create multiple threads when a button is clicked and i've done that with this:

```
Dim myThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf getFile)
myThread.IsBackground = True
myThread.Start()
```

but i need to update a picture box with the downloaded file, buy if i set an event in the function getFile and raise it to notify that the files was downloaded and then update the picturebox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an [AsyncResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.asyncresult.aspx), and either check it periodically for completion, or provide a delegate to be called when the thread has completed its work.

A complete example in VB [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.asyncresult(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use of MethodInvoker deligate.

```
Public Sub GetFile()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(GetFile)) 
    End If
End Sub
```

Now you can handle any event in your specified class.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive that using the Asyncallback, ...

```
Dim sinctotal As New Del_sinc(AddressOf sincronizar)

Dim ar As IAsyncResult = sinctotal.BeginInvoke(_funcion, type, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf SincEnd), cookieobj)
```

The cookieobj is this

```
Class Cookie

    Public id As String
    Public AsyncDelegate As [Delegate]
    Sub New(ByVal id As String, ByVal asyncDelegate As [Delegate])

        Me.id = id
        Me.AsyncDelegate = asyncDelegate

    End Sub


End Class
```

When the delegate finish it will call the funcion Sincend (in this example), then you could use a event to update your picture.

Hope this helps!